# Is the following code thread unsafe? Is so, how can I make a possible result more likely to come out?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, concurrency, thread-safety

Is the screen output of the following program deterministic? My understanding is that it is not, as it could be either 1 or 2 depending on whether the latest thread to pick up the value of `i` picks it up before or after the other thread has written 1 into it.

On the other, hand I keep seeing the same output as if each thread waits the previous to finish, as in I get 2 on screen in this case, or 100 if I create similar threads from `t1` to `t100` and join them all.

If the answer is *no, the result is not deterministic*, is there a way with a simple toy program to increase the odds that the one of the possible results comes out?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main() {

    int i = 0;

    std::thread t1([&i](){ ++i; });
    std::thread t2([&i](){ ++i; });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

(I'm compiling and running it like this: `g++ -std=c++11 -lpthread prova.cpp -o exe && ./exe`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are always seeing the same result because the first thread starts and runs its operations before the second one. This narrows the window for a race condition to occur.

But ultimately, there is still a chance that it occurs because the ++ operation is not atomic (read value, then increment, then write).

If the two threads start at the same time (eg: thread 1 slowed down due to the CPU being busy), then they will read the same value and the final result will be 1.

Comment: Agreed. The amount of work being done in the threads is so small the window for producing the output of `1` is very narrow (but definitely possible). Mutex protecting the `++i` would guarantee output value of `2` every time.